# EMM Login Error Cannot read property "prodConsumerKey"

Tags: authentication, wso2, setup-deployment, wso2-iot

I've downloaded EMM 1.1.0 and configured a vm with all the pre-requites to run it.

Since I"m working from the local machines and the VM is a ubuntu server setup I have renamed all of the localhost in the config file to reflect the proper domain name so it can reach.

When I point my browser to https://mydomain.com:9443  I am able to login to carbon and change usernames

However when I goto https://mydomain.com:9443/emm/ it asks me to login again... when I do I get the following errors:
500: Something has gone wrong  (very helpful!)

On the console/log file I capture the following:

```
[2014-06-24 10:06:34,041]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2014-06-24 10:06:34,041+0800]
[2014-06-24 10:06:34,321]  INFO {JAGGERY.modules.common:js} -  New connection was taken
[2014-06-24 10:06:34,618]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2014-06-24 10:06:34,618+0800]
[2014-06-24 10:06:34,630] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject} -  Login failed! Please recheck the username and password and try again..
[2014-06-24 10:06:35,154]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2014-06-24 10:06:35,154+0800]
[2014-06-24 10:06:35,156] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} -  Login failed! Please recheck the username and password and try again.
[2014-06-24 10:06:35,326] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "prodConsumerKey" from undefined (/emm/modules/startup.js#59)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "prodConsumerKey" from undefined (/emm/modules/startup.js#59)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:447)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
```

... many many more

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

If the admin password  is changed, you have to modify the api-manager config file.
A good practice should be create new user for the api-manager

This miss-configuration also causes blank page after EMM authentication in multi-tenancy.

**/repository/conf/api-manager.xml**

```
   <!--
    Authentication manager configuration for API publisher and API store. This is
    a required configuration for both web applications as their user authentication
    logic relies on this.
-->
<AuthManager>
    <!--
        Server URL of the Authentication service
    -->
    <ServerURL>https://${carbon.local.ip}:${mgt.transport.https.port}/services/</ServerURL>
    <!--
        Admin username for the Authentication manager.
    -->
    <Username>apiuser</Username>
    <!--
        Admin password for the Authentication manager.
    -->
    <Password>StrongPassword</Password>
</AuthManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed username and password of the admin you will have to change that in config.json file found in `wso2emm-1.1.0\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\emm\config`. Just update the username and password in apiManagerConfigurations section and restart the EMM server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a public JIRA regarding this[1].

The workaround is

You have to set admin username and password to admin and admin when first login to EMM.

If you have changed the password of admin please set the password to admin.

You can use chpasswd.sh/chpasswd.bin file in the bin folder to change the password.

Eg:

./chpasswd.sh --db-url "jdbc:h2:/repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB" --db-username wso2carbon -db-password wso2carbon --username admin --new-password admin

Once you login to EMM first time, please use above command to change the password again

[1]. https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-704

Comment: I never change any password and I got Same error!
What can be?

Comment: The command line not work at Mysql, alway give error 'Access denied for user':
I try tree users "root", "dcbasso" and "wos2carbon" and nothing. All users can logon in mysql command line, but not in this chpasswd.sh!

Answer (score 0):

I used mysql as my DB: Documentation tell you to place the connector file in `${CARBON_HOME}/repository/components/lib`.

Running

```
${CARBON_HOME}/bin/./chpasswd.sh --db-url jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/wso2emm_db --db-username user_db --db-password pass --username admin --new-password admin
```

I got this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://

Copying the connector file to `${CARBON_HOME}/repository/lib` solved my issue.